# Nested form won't display for has_one relationship Simple_Form (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I set my user model up to build the user_profile before being created. The user_profile itself is being shown in the console when I load the user object. @user = User.find(1) -> @user.user_profile -> UserProfile Load. The relationship works correctly. The issue is I am unable to make changes to the user profile with the edit user_profile action. The edit page is empty, even though the attributes for the user_profile exist. How can I get the form to load in the edit view, so that the user is able to make changes to his/her profile after logging into their account? Side note: The user does not edit their normal profile during registration.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  before_create :build_user_profile
  extend FriendlyId

  after_validation :geocode

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

  has_one :user_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile

  protected
  def confirmation_required?
    false
  end
end
```

user_profile.rb

```
class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :avatar, UserAvatarUploader
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy

  validates_integrity_of  :avatar
  validates_processing_of :avatar

end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user_profile, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <% f.simple_fields_for :user_profile do |user_profile| %>
          <div class="col-md-4">
        <% if current_user.user_profile.avatar.url.present? %>
            <%= image_tag(current_user.user_profile.avatar.url) %>
            <%= user_profile.label :remove_avatar do %>
                <%= user_profile.input :remove_avatar, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
            <% end %>
            <%= user_profile.input :avatar, as: :file, class: 'form-control' %>
            <%= user_profile.input :birthday, label: false, id: 'datepicker', class: 'form-control' %>

        <% end %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= f.button :submit %>
              </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

schema.rb

```
 create_table "user_profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "birthday"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "avatar"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_profiles_on_user_id"
  end
```

user_profiles_controller.rb

```
class UserProfilesController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :set_user_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :load_profile, only: [:edit, :update]

  def show

  end

  # GET /user_profiles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /user_profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /user_profiles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_profile.update(user_profile_params)
        format.html {redirect_to @user_profile, notice: 'User profile was successfully updated.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :ok, location: @user_profile}
      else
        format.html {render :edit}
        format.json {render json: @user_profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def load_profile
    @user_profile = current_user.user_profile
  end


  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def user_profile_params
    params.require(:user).permit(user_profile: [:birthday, :avatar, :user_id])
  end
end
```

Rails Console

```
@user = User.find(5)
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<User id: 5, email: "colejohn@hotmail.com", username: "johnny", first_name: "John", last_name: "Woo">
>> @user.user_profile
  UserProfile Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "user_profiles".* FROM "user_profiles" WHERE "user_profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<UserProfile id: 2, birthday: nil, user_id: 5, created_at: "2017-08-17 20:47:12", updated_at: "2017-08-17 20:47:12", avatar: nil>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The edit page is empty, even though the attributes for the
>   user_profile exist.

This line

```
<% f.simple_fields_for :user_profile do |user_profile| %>
```

should be

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :user_profile do |user_profile| %>
```

You are missing `=`, which is the reason for the form being empty.

Comment: I'm getting ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user_profile): after making the changes. I tried to setup the strong parameters but its not working

Comment: Your strong params should be `params.require(:user_profile).permit( :birthday, :avatar, :user_id)`

Comment: The form is not populating. There must be a better way to load the user_profile than the approach I'm taking. I can only see the predefined labels. None of the inputs are showing.

Comment: @JohnnyC Keep your strong params as it is before and try changing this `<%= simple_form_for(@user_profile, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>` to `<%= simple_form_for(current_user, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>`

Comment: I tried with the current_user object. But, the form still doesn't display.

Comment: I made it work. The form was being hidden by the if statement for the avatar!

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I really appreciate the effort.

Comment: @JohnnyC Glad you figured it out. Also remember that yiu are missing = in this line `<% f.simple_fields_for :user_profile do |user_profile| %>` It should be `<%= f.simple_fields_for :user_profile do |user_profile| %>`

Comment: I agree. I will try to vote your solution up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Misplaced if statement termination **<% end %>** in simple_form

```
<% if current_user.user_profile.avatar.url.present? %>
            <%= image_tag(current_user.user_profile.avatar.url) %>
            <%= user_profile.label :remove_avatar do %>
                <%= user_profile.input :remove_avatar, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
            <% end %>
         <% end %>
```